# Google Analytics: Get all App Data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to fetch all App data, number of installs, new installs, etc, but I want overall results:

I have the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?dimensions=ga%3AmobileDeviceInfo%2Cga%3AappVersion%2Cga%3AappName%2Cga%3AappInstallerId%2Cga%3AappId&metrics=ga%3Ausers%2Cga%3AnewUsers%2Cga%3ApercentNewSessions&start-date=2014-04-30&end-date=2014-05-14&max-results=50
```

But it gives me many results in a date interval. Isn't there a way just to grab

```
Downloaded apps / OS
Active apps (installs that is still in phone)
uninstalls
```

That's it. I don't need anything more, just need this info. Can I get it back in one resultset?